# Normalize [code-first] and [ef-code-first] usage

Tags: support, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

I think all the questions tagged with [code-first](/questions/tagged/code-first) or [codefirst](/questions/tagged/codefirst), 
and ***in the same time*** with [entity-framwork](/questions/tagged/entity-framwork) (or [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) or [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23).

are regarding Entity Framework Code First,

so [ef-code-first](/questions/tagged/ef-code-first) is the most suitable tag for them.

**Stats:**

- <s>[codefirst](/questions/tagged/codefirst) has 67 questions.</s>
- <s>[code-first](/questions/tagged/code-first) has 585 questions, has [code-only](/questions/tagged/code-only) as a synonym and [codeonly](/questions/tagged/codeonly) as a suggested synonym (with 0 votes).</s>
- [ef4-code-only](/questions/tagged/ef4-code-only) has 92 questions.
- [ef-code-first](/questions/tagged/ef-code-first) has 1518 questions.

**Update:** Now only [115](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-first+-entity-framework+-c#+-asp.net+-asp.net-4.0+-ef-code-first+-.net+-vb.net+-entity-framework-4.1) questions from [854](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-first) are tagged by [code-first](/questions/tagged/code-first) and not with any .NET stack related technology. Or even more!

This means that **this tag is used incorrectly** in ~90% of cases!

Comment: At least `[codefirst]` should be a synonym for `[code-first]`.

Comment: Don't co-opt general tags for specific uses! That's what happened in the Android tag with [tag:activity] and [tag:intent], and it's a big mess now.

Comment: @RobertHarvey just for the record, I don't necessarily agree with OP.

Comment: @Robert: True. But still the most of the code-first questions are Entity Framework related!

Comment: @Robert: And even synonimation is not done.

Answer (score 4):

[codefirst] => [code-first] **Si!**

=> [ef-code-first]  **No!**

Code-first is also used to describe design patterns where the code literally comes before other concerns.  A common example is an alternative to contract-first web service design.

If anything, those questions should be retagged to the *ef* version of the tag.

Comment: Globally - yes, but I'm sure that all the posts tagged with `[code-fifst]` and `entity-framework` are regarding `ef-code-first`, aren't they?

Comment: I don't think that `[code-first]` makes sense, really. It's too vague

Comment: @abatishchev: Eh, possibly.  But It *does* describe a general pattern of software development where you write code before you do anything else...

Comment: +1 Retagging would require some work but makes the most sense.

Comment: @Won't: [codefist] still is not a synonym for [code-first], support please.

Comment: @abatishchev done

Comment: Thanks! May I ask the same for [ef-code-only] and [ef-code-first]?

Comment: @abatishchev will look into it

Answer (score 0):

[code-first](/questions/tagged/code-first) is more intuitive than [ef-code-first](/questions/tagged/ef-code-first). You might want to put the ef at the end. Try [code-first-ef](/questions/tagged/code-first-ef) instead. Tag suggestions will help here.

Comment: But the product's name is Entity Framework Code First. So tag should be name correlatively.